# Disable or change IPTables firewall file based

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, virtual-machines

We have a server that became inaccessibel after our network supplier changed out external IP adres.

The server runs ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and access to port 22 is limited to our old IP. Only ports 8080, and 443 (Tomcat, SSL and non-SSL) is available.

The server is a virtual server, hosted by a third party. I can boot the server into a recovery mode, where I can access the whole filesystem under /recovery. Afterwords a can boot up again.

Question is, what changes I can make to the file system, so that I can access the server after reboot.

Ideally disable, or change iptables firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Search for the rule that sets your address. Try `/etc` first and then the whole disk.

```
# Your old IP address
IP=1.2.3.4
grep -r $IP /recovery/etc
grep -r $IP /recovery
```

You should get some hits. Ignore log files. If you find something that looks like iptables rules, replace the old address with the new address.

If that doesn't work, create a cron job that clears iptables or allows your address that runs a few minutes after boot.